# How to check if a max value position has previously been found C++

Tags: c++, arrays

As part of a larger function, I am iterating over a two dimensional array to find the position of the max value in each row.

```
pos = std::distance(A_T[k].begin(), std::max_element(A_T[k].begin(), A_T[k].end(), 
            [](T a, T b) {return (abs(a) < abs(b)); }));
```

Since my array is 2D, it is possible to receive the same position twice - In this case, I would like to return the position of the next largest value.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: you mean it is possible to get the same column twice?

Comment: Yes, I would like to never find the same column twice

Comment: `nth_element` will give you access to the 2nd, 3rd, etc largest - however it is a sorting algorithm, so if you can't mutate the source data then you'll need to copy it. I see a possible solution would be to keep a `set` / `unordered_set` of previously seen results, updated with the result of each row. You would then have to iteratively check `nth_element` with an incrementing counter each time the previous result already exists in your set.

Comment: Prepare a container of bool values, All `false` initially. Same size as your row (columns number) and every time you find a max integer, mark that index as `true`. Design and test it in a way that if that index is already `true`, then ignore and search again. Maybe sort a copy and take the next index and so on

Comment: Perhaps you could copy the source data, and then for each row, you find `max_element` and remove that column from the source data. This would satisfy the constraint that each column can only be returned once

Comment: These are both things I haven't tried. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the solution proposed by [Steve Lorrimer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/955273/steve-lorimer).

I began by initializing a vector of max position history. I then looped over the position history vector, setting the corresponding columns of A_T to 0.0. I could then repeat the search for the next maximum, satisfying my requirement that the same column could not be picked twice.

Here is my code:

```
std::vector<unsigned> posHist;
for (unsigned k = 0; k < A.size(); k++)
{
    for (unsigned q = 0; q < posHist.size(); q++)
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < A_T.size(); i++)
            A_T[i][posHist[q]] = 0.0;

    posHist.push_back (std::distance(A_T[k].begin(),
        std::max_element(A_T[k].begin(), A_T[k].end(),
           [](T a, T b) {return (abs(a) < abs(b)));}));
}
```